# ⌘+Tab app list filtering

Tags: mac, macos

Is there any way to hide apps without windows from ⌘+Tab app list? So I could close skype, mail, adium, etc. and still receive notifications from those apps. So for example when I receive message in windowless skype and it creates a window I can switch to skype, But skype window does not appear in ⌘+Tab app list, since I switch a lot at work.

Comment: It’s probably similar to this question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153854/osx-only-show-apps-with-open-windows-in-the-dock/153869#153869

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I found as program called "Witch" which may help you. It's got a free trial on the website, but it does eventually costs $14. Check it out, it's got everything you want it seems.
**Website:** http://manytricks.com/witch/
**App Store:** https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/witch/id412485838?mt=12

Comment: Thanks! I've already tried "Witch" and several other apps that modify cmd-tab behavior. "Witch" is probably the closest to what I want, but with very little customization options.